# Finding limit of a function ($0$ appears in denominator)

Tags: limits

This is the function:
$$f(x)= \frac{x^3 + 3x^2+2x}{x^2-2x-8} $$
So I tried to find this limit:
$$\lim_{x\to -2}\frac{x^3 + 3x^2+2x}{x^2-2x-8}=\left[\frac{-8-12-4}{4+4-8}=\frac{-24}{0}\right]= \lim_{x\to -2}\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)}{(x-4)(x+2)}$$
This isn't a case where numerator and denominator, after factorization, have some elements which can reduce a "problematic" element... I need to get rid of $(x+2)$ which makes the fraction explode but I don't know how.

Comment: $\color{red}+12$. And $x^3+3x^2+2x=x(x\color{red}+2)(x\color{red}+1)$.

Comment: What is that u doing in the denominator? Shouldnt that be a x?

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule

Comment: @CBenni editor displays 'x' but here it displays 'u'.

Comment: @kr85: Did you try a series expansion? Regards

Comment: @DavidMitra Lapsus calami :/

Comment: Thank you all! I haven't read the task correctly and in the end it was a type of a task where factors reduce. But, now curious how to solve this kind of task where elements don't reduce. (We haven't yet learned L'Hôpital's rule. Is there another way ? )

Comment: If the numerator has finite, non-zero limit, and the denominator has a zero limit, then the limit is infinite or doesn't exist.  For example $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow1} {4\over (x-1)^2}=\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow1} {4\over  x-1 }$ does not exist (the limit from the right is $\infty$ and the limit from the left is $-\infty$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have factor wrong your function, just do it in the following way
$$\lim_{x\to -2}\frac{x^3 + 3x^2+2x}{x^2-2x-8} = \lim_{x \to -2} \frac{x(x+1)(x+2)}{(x-4)(x+2)} = \lim_{x \to -2} \frac{x(x+1)}{(x-4)} = \frac{-2(-2+1)}{-2-4} = -\frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant $$f(x)=\frac{x^3+3x^2+2x}{x^2-2x-8}$$

Then $\lim_{x\to2-}f(x)$ is a indeterminate form or type $\frac{0}{0}$, therefore we apply l'Hopital rule and receive
$$\lim_{x\to2-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to2-}\frac{3x^2+6x+2}{2x-2}=\frac{3\cdot4-2\cdot6+2}{-2\cdot2-2}=\frac{2}{-6}=-\frac{1}{3}$$